# Kubernetes add Domain Name & SSL

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, certificate, cloud, ovh

I installed a **Kubernetes** cluster on my cloud. I deployed an application with a pod, a service ... And the **external IP** obtained is a domain name (6ssv5s4gc.lb.c4.gra8.k8s.ovh.net), which is a bit problematic, because I cannot add an **SSL certificate**. I tried with NGINX Ingress but I can't.
Did you have a solution?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/tls/

Comment: @MaxSliw  It's doable with Matt link, If you find difficulties reproducing to your scenario please illustrate your question, post what you have done your configuration files too so we can help adequately.

Comment: I advanced on my problem, for that I followed this tutorial. Unfortunately I still can't get a certificate. I'm still looking for a solution. It may be from my host.

Comment: please update your question, tell us how much you advanced and what is your current problems, your question may help others.

Comment: Please check - stackhttps://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am waiting for a real solution and then I will update my post.